# Sort Data By the 2nd Last Letter in a cell then the first- Google Apps Script / Google Sheets

Tags: arrays, sorting, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

In the image shown (highlighted Bright Green G:H), I would have liked to sort the data according to the 2nd last letter - not the first. This would have meant F01A1 should have been appeared higher in list than E09C1, and then would have been selected in the A column.

How could I have the data Sorted by 2nd Last Letter in Cell, in Column G:H ?

[image]

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Comment: Player0 here you go https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QgjH2ehc8qM1d40lshSTBU0lUHWrqkxOSMNl8ejmWzY/edit#gid=1467092802

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try in row 1:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({G:H, RIGHT(H:H, 2)}, "select Col1,Col2 order by Col3", 0))
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: Igor - This sheet is part of an Inventory System I am building for the charity I work for. I am truly indebted to all who have helped provide answers to my questions. All I am asking for here is assistance to find stock in different locations in our warehouse. If someone marks Column A (indicating low stock) it will alert us to get that stock from the highlighted Green cells in Column G:H. hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned Google Apps Script, you could use the following [custom function](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions) to sort the data:

```js
function CUSTOMSORT(input) {
  input.sort(function(a, b) {
    if (a[0].slice(-2) < b[0].slice(-2)) {
      return -1;
    } else if (a[0].slice(-2) > b[0].slice(-2)) {
      return 1;
    }
    return 0;    
  })
  return input;
}
```

Once it is defined, you can use this function the same you would any sheets built-in function. For example, if you want to sort data from `A1:A10`, just call the function like this:

`=CUSTOMSORT(A1:A10)`

#### Reference:

- [Custom Functions in Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions)
- [Array.prototype.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)
- [Array.prototype.slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)